# is there any way to use if-else statement in mysql other than sp and functions?

Tags: mysql

is there any way to use if-else statement in mysql outside sps and functions in ad hoc queries? It can be easily done is MS SQL.
This is my query:

```
SET @Flag := 'u', @appUserID := 0;

SELECT app_user_id
INTO @appUserID
FROM app_user
WHERE user_login_id = @UserLoginID;

IF @Flag = 'u' THEN
    SELECT @appUserID;  
END IF;
```

I receive this error: "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @Flag = 'u' THEN  SELECT @appUserID' at line 1"

Comment: IF/ELSE logic should work in MySQL too: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: if zthen work only in stored procedures, so where are you running this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this in a normal query tab, you can use DDL

```
SET @Flag := 'u', @appUserID := 0;

SELECT app_user_id
INTO @appUserID
FROM app_user
WHERE user_login_id = @UserLoginID;

SELECT IF(@Flag = 'u',@sql := "SELECT @appUserID;  ",@sql := "DO NULL");
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: Thanks, it can work only if I have two conditions ie if and else not in the case of multiple if, else if cases. I assume it is the equivalent of IIF() in sql server.

Comment: mys ql IF(cond,trueresult, false result) in case of multiple you can switch to CASE WGEN or nest the IF clause